# How to directly render pi camera output to display using C++

Tags: c++, picamera, mmal

Right now, I'm building an application and one of the sub goals is to display the camera to the screen with a good resolution and frame rate. I'm also trying to keep the cpu usage as low as possible since there'll be other tasks running in the background. I've tried multiple solutions, but I think I've found one that would be great if I could implement.

Current list of solutions:

- Using OpenCV and accessing through /dev/video0 (lots of CPU usage and oddly low FPS)
- Using the raspicam library with OpenCV (less CPU usage but low FPS)
- Using the picamera library (perfect, but not C++)

After digging some more, I found out that the MMAL library does exactly what I'm trying to do. The only problem is that I'm a bit confused on how to implement it? Documentation is subpar without any code examples so I'm not sure how I would go ahead with implementing it.

A few of the references I looked at were the `raspicam` folder in the raspberry pi userland repo and the raspicam library's private folder [(this one)](https://github.com/cedricve/raspicam/blob/master/src/private/private_impl.cpp). It seems as if the raspicam library uses the RaspiStill as a base for its code, but doesn't use the preview connection that I need.

I was able to get this much from the raspistill file in the userland repo but it only says "SUCCESS":

```
#include <iostream>

#include "interface/mmal/mmal.h"
#include "interface/mmal/mmal_logging.h"
#include "interface/mmal/mmal_buffer.h"
#include "interface/mmal/util/mmal_util.h"
#include "interface/mmal/util/mmal_util_params.h"
#include "interface/mmal/util/mmal_default_components.h"
#include "interface/mmal/util/mmal_connection.h"

MMAL_COMPONENT_T *preview_component;
MMAL_COMPONENT_T *camera_component;

MMAL_STATUS_T raspipreview_create()
{
   MMAL_COMPONENT_T *preview = 0;
   MMAL_PORT_T *preview_port = NULL;
   MMAL_STATUS_T status;

   status = mmal_component_create(MMAL_COMPONENT_DEFAULT_VIDEO_RENDERER,
                                  &preview);

   if (status != MMAL_SUCCESS)
   {
      vcos_log_error("Unable to create preview component");
      goto error;
   }

   if (!preview->input_num)
   {
      status = MMAL_ENOSYS;
      vcos_log_error("No input ports found on component");
      goto error;
   }

   preview_port = preview->input[0];

   MMAL_DISPLAYREGION_T param;
   param.hdr.id = MMAL_PARAMETER_DISPLAYREGION;
   param.hdr.size = sizeof(MMAL_DISPLAYREGION_T);

   param.set = MMAL_DISPLAY_SET_LAYER;
   param.layer = 2;

   param.set |= MMAL_DISPLAY_SET_ALPHA;
   param.alpha = 255;

   /* I don't know whether a full screen preview is needed or a windowed
       * view, but I'm keeping the full screen for now.
      if (state->wantFullScreenPreview)
      {
         param.set |= MMAL_DISPLAY_SET_FULLSCREEN;
         param.fullscreen = 1;
      }
      else
      {
         param.set |= (MMAL_DISPLAY_SET_DEST_RECT | MMAL_DISPLAY_SET_FULLSCREEN);
         param.fullscreen = 0;
         param.dest_rect = state->previewWindow;
      }
      */

   param.set |= MMAL_DISPLAY_SET_FULLSCREEN;
   param.fullscreen = 1;

   /* Defaults to -1 so this code is not needed
      if (state->display_num >= 0)
      {
         param.set |= MMAL_DISPLAY_SET_NUM;
         param.display_num = state->display_num;
      }
      */

   status = mmal_port_parameter_set(preview_port, &param.hdr);

   if (status != MMAL_SUCCESS && status != MMAL_ENOSYS)
   {
      vcos_log_error("unable to set preview port parameters (%u)", status);
      goto error;
   }

   /* Enable component */
   status = mmal_component_enable(preview);
   if (status != MMAL_SUCCESS)
   {
      vcos_log_error("Unable to enable preview/null sink component (%u)", status);
      goto error;
   }

   preview_component = preview;

   return status;

error:

   if (preview)
      mmal_component_destroy(preview);
   return status;
}

void raspipreview_destroy()
{
   if (preview_component)
   {
      mmal_component_destroy(preview_component);
      preview_component = NULL;
   }
}

void default_camera_control_callback(MMAL_PORT_T *port, MMAL_BUFFER_HEADER_T *buffer)
{
   fprintf(stderr, "Camera control callback  cmd=0x%08x", buffer->cmd);

   if (buffer->cmd == MMAL_EVENT_PARAMETER_CHANGED)
   {
      MMAL_EVENT_PARAMETER_CHANGED_T *param = (MMAL_EVENT_PARAMETER_CHANGED_T *)buffer->data;
      switch (param->hdr.id)
      {
      case MMAL_PARAMETER_CAMERA_SETTINGS:
      {
         MMAL_PARAMETER_CAMERA_SETTINGS_T *settings = (MMAL_PARAMETER_CAMERA_SETTINGS_T *)param;
         vcos_log_error("Exposure now %u, analog gain %u/%u, digital gain %u/%u",
                        settings->exposure,
                        settings->analog_gain.num, settings->analog_gain.den,
                        settings->digital_gain.num, settings->digital_gain.den);
         vcos_log_error("AWB R=%u/%u, B=%u/%u",
                        settings->awb_red_gain.num, settings->awb_red_gain.den,
                        settings->awb_blue_gain.num, settings->awb_blue_gain.den);
      }
      break;
      }
   }
   else if (buffer->cmd == MMAL_EVENT_ERROR)
   {
      vcos_log_error("No data received from sensor. Check all connections, including the Sunny one on the camera board");
   }
   else
   {
      vcos_log_error("Received unexpected camera control callback event, 0x%08x", buffer->cmd);
   }

   mmal_buffer_header_release(buffer);
}

static MMAL_STATUS_T create_camera_component()
{
   MMAL_COMPONENT_T *camera = 0;
   MMAL_ES_FORMAT_T *format;
   MMAL_PORT_T *preview_port = NULL, *video_port = NULL, *still_port = NULL;
   MMAL_STATUS_T status;

   /* Create the component */
   status = mmal_component_create(MMAL_COMPONENT_DEFAULT_CAMERA, &camera);

   if (status != MMAL_SUCCESS)
   {
      vcos_log_error("Failed to create camera component");
      if (camera) mmal_component_destroy(camera);
      return status;

   }

   if (status != MMAL_SUCCESS)
   {
      vcos_log_error("Could not set stereo mode : error %d", status);
      if (camera) mmal_component_destroy(camera);
      return status;

   }

   MMAL_PARAMETER_INT32_T camera_num =
       {{MMAL_PARAMETER_CAMERA_NUM, sizeof(camera_num)}, 0};

   status = mmal_port_parameter_set(camera->control, &camera_num.hdr);

   if (status != MMAL_SUCCESS)
   {
      vcos_log_error("Could not select camera : error %d", status);
      if (camera) mmal_component_destroy(camera);
      return status;

   }

   if (!camera->output_num)
   {
      status = MMAL_ENOSYS;
      vcos_log_error("Camera doesn't have output ports");
      if (camera) mmal_component_destroy(camera);
      return status;

   }

   status = mmal_port_parameter_set_uint32(camera->control, MMAL_PARAMETER_CAMERA_CUSTOM_SENSOR_CONFIG, 0);

   if (status != MMAL_SUCCESS)
   {
      vcos_log_error("Could not set sensor mode : error %d", status);
      if (camera) mmal_component_destroy(camera);
      return status;
   }

   preview_port = camera->output[0];
   video_port = camera->output[1];
   still_port = camera->output[2];

   // Enable the camera, and tell it its control callback function
   status = mmal_port_enable(camera->control, default_camera_control_callback);

   if (status != MMAL_SUCCESS)
   {
      vcos_log_error("Unable to enable control port : error %d", status);
      if (camera) mmal_component_destroy(camera);
      return status;
   }

   //  set up the camera configuration
   {
      MMAL_PARAMETER_CAMERA_CONFIG_T cam_config =
          {
              {MMAL_PARAMETER_CAMERA_CONFIG, sizeof(cam_config)},
              .max_stills_w = 1280,
              .max_stills_h = 720,
              .stills_yuv422 = 0,
              .one_shot_stills = 1,
              .max_preview_video_w = 1280,
              .max_preview_video_h = 720,
              .num_preview_video_frames = 3,
              .stills_capture_circular_buffer_height = 0,
              .fast_preview_resume = 0,
              .use_stc_timestamp = MMAL_PARAM_TIMESTAMP_MODE_RESET_STC};

      cam_config.max_preview_video_w = 1280;
      cam_config.max_preview_video_h = 720;

      mmal_port_parameter_set(camera->control, &cam_config.hdr);
   }

   // Now set up the port formats

   format = preview_port->format;
   format->encoding = MMAL_ENCODING_OPAQUE;
   format->encoding_variant = MMAL_ENCODING_I420;

   // In this mode we are forcing the preview to be generated from the full capture resolution.
   // This runs at a max of 15fps with the OV5647 sensor.
   format->es->video.width = VCOS_ALIGN_UP(1280, 32);
   format->es->video.height = VCOS_ALIGN_UP(720, 16);
   format->es->video.crop.x = 0;
   format->es->video.crop.y = 0;
   format->es->video.crop.width = 1280;
   format->es->video.crop.height = 720;
   format->es->video.frame_rate.num = 0;
   format->es->video.frame_rate.den = 1;

   status = mmal_port_format_commit(preview_port);
   if (status != MMAL_SUCCESS)
   {
      vcos_log_error("camera viewfinder format couldn't be set");
      if (camera) mmal_component_destroy(camera);
      return status;
   }

   // Set the same format on the video  port (which we don't use here)
   mmal_format_full_copy(video_port->format, format);
   status = mmal_port_format_commit(video_port);

   if (status != MMAL_SUCCESS)
   {
      vcos_log_error("camera video format couldn't be set");
      if (camera) mmal_component_destroy(camera);
      return status;
   }

   // Ensure there are enough buffers to avoid dropping frames
   if (video_port->buffer_num < 3)
      video_port->buffer_num = 3;

   /* Ensure there are enough buffers to avoid dropping frames */
   if (still_port->buffer_num < 3)
      still_port->buffer_num = 3;

   /* Enable component */
   status = mmal_component_enable(camera);

   if (status != MMAL_SUCCESS)
   {
      vcos_log_error("camera component couldn't be enabled");
      if (camera) mmal_component_destroy(camera);
      return status;
   }

   camera_component = camera;

   return status;
}


static void destroy_camera_component()
{
   if (camera_component)
   {
      mmal_component_destroy(camera_component);
      camera_component = NULL;
   }
}

int main()
{
   std::cout << mmal_status_to_string(raspipreview_create());
   std::cout << mmal_status_to_string(create_camera_component());

   sleep(10);

   destroy_camera_component();
   raspipreview_destroy();
   return 0;
}
```

I'm assuming it only says SUCCESS without actually showing anything to the screen. It even activates the camera (activity light turns on) but yet, nothing on the screen. Could someone help with me? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nevermind, got it working! I was missing the code to link up the preview component to the camera. Here's the missing code:

```
...
MMAL_CONNECTION_T *preview_connection; // Global variable

...
MMAL_STATUS_T connect_ports(MMAL_PORT_T * output_port, MMAL_PORT_T * input_port, MMAL_CONNECTION_T ** connection) {
  MMAL_STATUS_T status;
  status = mmal_connection_create(connection, output_port, input_port, MMAL_CONNECTION_FLAG_TUNNELLING | MMAL_CONNECTION_FLAG_ALLOCATION_ON_INPUT);
  if (status == MMAL_SUCCESS) {
    status = mmal_connection_enable( * connection);
    if (status != MMAL_SUCCESS) mmal_connection_destroy( * connection);
  }
  return status;
}

...

int main() {
  MMAL_PORT_T * camera_preview_port = NULL;
  MMAL_PORT_T * preview_input_port = NULL;
  std::cout << mmal_status_to_string(create_camera_component());
  std::cout << mmal_status_to_string(raspipreview_create());
  camera_preview_port = camera_component -> output[0];
  preview_input_port = preview_component -> input[0];
  connect_ports(camera_preview_port, preview_input_port, & preview_connection);
  sleep(10);
  destroy_camera_component();
  raspipreview_destroy();
  return 0;
}
```